# How to keep menu closed on new page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a class that activates when a button is clicked and closes a menu but when a new page is loaded it reruns the script and the class is no longer active so the menu is open again. I need the class to stay active when the button is clicked and a new page is opened. For example: the menu is open by default and you click to close it, but right now if you open a new page the menu is open on that new page instead of closed.
Here is the code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".closed").click(function(){
    $(".circle").toggle(1000);
});
});
</script>
```

I just need to add something so the class stays active on a new page after the initial load of the home page.

Comment: use    .circle{display:none;} in your css

Comment: i only want it to not display after the user closes the menu and then navigates to another page

Comment: Did you tried my code??

Comment: that will make the class always display none.

Comment: actually that worked. Thanks